# Change modern library logo

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-document-library

My modern libraries are showing the site logo cropped in a square area in the "AllItems.aspx" view and I want to remove this logo or change it for a smaller one without changing the site logo. How can I do this?

Comment: My bad, there is no support to add custom CSS to the modern libraries right now, so i were wrong.

Comment: I supposed that, I think it should not show the site logo in the header of the modern document libraries, which is often not a square. This header should show the initials of the document library title or another logo different than the site logo.